# Oracle - Order by Alpha numeric

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to order the rows in my result set by a column that holds varchar2 K-12.

Example:

```
ID Grade Expense
1 1 500
1 10 500
1 11 500
1 12 500
1 2 500
1 3 500
1 4 500
1 5 500
1 6 500
1 7 500
1 8 500
1 9 500
1 K 500
```

> This is my order by clause which works, but I would like to have the
>   row with Grade = K as the first row for each ID in my result set.

```
order by ID, to_number(regexp_substr(grade, '^[[:digit:]]*'))
```

> As it stands, the result set has the row with ID = K is last and not
>   first.  How can i make it the first row for each ID in my result set?

```
ID Grade Expense
1 K 500
1 1 500
1 2 500
1 3 500
1 4 500
1 5 500
1 6 500
1 7 500
1 8 500
1 9 500
1 10 500
1 11 500
1 12 500
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a case statement to set K to something below 1.  this has the advantage if you have a Pre-K later, you can modify the case to handle it as well.

```
With CTE as 
  (SELECT '1' as grade from dual union 
   SELECT '2' from dual union 
   select '10' from dual union 
   select 'K' from dual)
SELECT * FROM CTE 
ORDER BY CASE GRADE when 'K' then -1 
                    else to_number(regexp_substr(grade, '^[[:digit:]]*')) end
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a kludge, but since the regex for 'K' returns null, change the order by to:

```
order by ID, nvl(to_number(regexp_substr(grade, '^[[:digit:]]*')),0)
```

This will return 0 for 'K' and sort it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Only change the `ORDER BY` clause, this way:

```
order by ID asc, decode(grade,'K',-1,grade) asc
```

Comment: You'll also want to convert `grade` to a number (I think what you have above will give a type mismatch plus it will sort ASCII meaning `12` will precede `2`, etc.).

Comment: No, I've tested with a column of type VARCHAR2(2), and he's sorting ASCending this way : K, 1, 2, 10, 12, 20 --- He's doing implicit conversion apparently. If you add one record with for example 'L', the same SELECT replies with `01722:Invalid Number`. But that means that if you make sure all generated values (1,2,10,12,20 but also -1) are numbers ... it works. (11gR2 database)

Comment: Apparently, the output of the first result is the data type which DECODE returns. In the above case, that is the data type of -1, which is a NUMBER. If column `GRADE` is a number (even if implicitally converted from VARCHAR2) for all other records, he's consequently converting to a number, and also ordering likewise. Until he spots a record from which he can't convert the value to a number, like 'L'. In that case, the Select indeed fails, and you would need other code. The OP didn't specify that case, but it could be interesting to include handling of other values.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
WITH g1 AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, TO_CHAR(level) AS grade, 500 AS expense FROM dual
 CONNECT BY level <= 12
   UNION
  SELECT 1, 'K', 500 FROM dual
   UNION
  SELECT 1, 'J', 500 FROM dual
)
SELECT g1.*, TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(grade, '^\d+'))
     , DECODE(grade, 'K', -1, TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(grade, '^\d+')))
  FROM g1
 ORDER BY DECODE(grade, 'K', -1, TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(grade, '^\d+'))) NULLS LAST
```

In this query I'm using `CONNECT BY` to build your grade table; of course you'll want to ignore that part. Note I added an extra row with a `J` for the grade level.

In my order by I am using `DECODE()` so that if `grade = 'K'`, it will give a value of `-1`. For any grades that can be converted to numeric values (that is, if they start with at least one digit), I use a regex to get as many digits if possible (you can use `[:digit:]` or `[0-9]` in place of `\d`; but `\d` is nice and short).

I am specifying `NULLS LAST` so that any rows for which `grade` cannot be converted to a number, other than `K`, will be last.

I'm including the extra computed columns just to give a glimpse into what is actually going on and how the values are generated. They aren't needed for the query.

[Please see SQL Fiddle demo here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/40168)